# Setting location of Grape configuration file

Tags: groovy, ivy, groovy-grape

How do you configure Grape to look for a *custom configuration file* at a location other than the default of `~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml`? Unfortunately the official documentation at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Grape appears to be incomplete and doesn't cover this particular case.

For example, I'd like to specify a path such as `$PROJECT_DIR/src/main/resources/groovyConfig.xml` so that other members in my team don't have to create and maintain their own `groovyConfig.xml` files in their user/home directories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To set a custom path to the Grape configuration file, set the `grape.config` system property, e.g. if `grape.config` is set to `/home/user/customGrapeConfig.xml` then Grape will use that as the configuration file.

The full list of options related to Grape configuration files, according to [a Groovy Developers' mailing list thread](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Global-grapeConfig-xml-td391461.html), is as follows:

1. Grape will use the value of the system property `grape.config` (if it is set) as the path to the configuration file.
2. If `grape.config` is not set, then:

   - If the `groovy.root` system property is set, Grape will look for the configuration file in the directory specified; otherwise
   - If `groovy.root` is not set, it uses `${user.home}/.groovy/` as the Groovy root directory and looks for a configuration file there.
3. If no configuration file is found to exist as per the previous steps, the `defaultGrapeConfig.xml` is retrieved from GrapeIvy's classloader (i.e. from the Groovy JAR).

Comment: This algorithm resides in https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=groovy.git;a=blob;f=src/main/groovy/grape/GrapeIvy.groovy

Comment: I wanted to integrate Groovy Grape/Ivy with a local Maven cache. GrapeIvy only reads Maven artifacts. A reimplementation that uses Maven for both reading and writing cached artifacts appears here: https://github.com/yihtserns/grape-maven

Comment: the new link for the algorithm is now https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=groovy.git;a=blob;f=src/main/groovy/groovy/grape/GrapeIvy.groovy (as per @eelghEEz comment)